# react- setState doesn't clear textbox

Tags: reactjs

I want to clear textbox fields on success or error. how can I do that.?

On success or error, calling a function to show the snack bar. Within that, I'm updating the state. but it is not working fine.

any help appreciated.!

### function

```
openSnackbar = ({ message }) => {
     this.setState({
         open: true,
         cp_currentPassword: '',
         cp_newPassword: '',
         cp_confirmPassword: '',
         message
     });
  };
```

### textfield

```
<TextField
     id="cp_currentPassword"
     label="Current Password"
     type="password"
     fullWidth
     className={classes.textField}
     value={this.state.cp_currentPassword}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     margin="normal"
     required={true}
/>;
```

### component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import GridItem from "../uiComponents/Grid/GridItem.jsx";
import GridContainer from "../uiComponents/Grid/GridContainer.jsx";
import Button from "../uiComponents/CustomButtons/Button.jsx";
import Card from "../uiComponents/Card/Card.jsx";
import CardHeader from "../uiComponents/Card/CardHeader.jsx";
import CardBody from "../uiComponents/Card/CardBody.jsx";
import CardFooter from "../uiComponents/Card/CardFooter.jsx";
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { changePassword } from '../../store/actions/auth'

const styles = {

    textField: {
        fontSize: '5px'
    },

};

class ChangePassword extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            open: false,
            message: '',
            cp_currentPassword: '',
            cp_newPassword: '',
            cp_confirmPassword: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
        const { authError } = this.props;
        console.log(authError)
        if (authError != prevProps.authError) {
            this.setState(
                {
                    loading: false,
                    message: authError,
                    open: true
                })
        }

    };
    
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    openSnackbar = ({ message }) => {
        this.setState({
            open: true,
            cp_currentPassword: '',
            cp_newPassword: '',
            cp_confirmPassword: '',
            message
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let curpass = this.state.cp_currentPassword
        let newpass = this.state.cp_newPassword
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        this.props.changePassword(curpass, newpass, this.passwordUpdated)
    }

    passwordUpdated = () => {
        this.setState({
            message: 'Password changed Successfully.!',
            open: true,
            loading: false,
            cp_currentPassword: '',
            cp_newPassword: '',
            cp_confirmPassword: ''
        });
    };


    render() {
        const { classes, auth, authError } = this.props;

        console.log(authError)
        const { loading } = this.state;
        const message = (
            <span
                id="snackbar-message-id"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.message }}
            />
        );
        if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin' />
        return (
            <div>
                {/* {authError ? this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' }) : null} */}
                {/* {authError && !this.state.open ? this.openSnackbar({ message: '{authError}' }) : null} */}
                <GridContainer>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>

                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader color="warning">
                                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Change Password</h4>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <form >
                                <GridContainer>
                                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                                        <CardBody>
                                            <GridContainer>
                                                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>

                                                    <TextField
                                                        id="cp_currentPassword"
                                                        label="Current Password"
                                                        type="password"
                                                        fullWidth
                                                        className={classes.textField}
                                                        value={this.state.cp_currentPassword}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                        margin="normal"
                                                        required={true}
                                                    />
                                                </GridItem>

                                                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                                                    <TextField
                                                        id="cp_newPassword"
                                                        label="New Password"
                                                        type="password"
                                                        fullWidth
                                                        className={classes.textField}
                                                        value={this.state.cp_newPassword}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                        margin="normal"
                                                        required={true}
                                                    />
                                                </GridItem>
                                                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                                                    <TextField
                                                        id="cp_confirmPassword"
                                                        label="Confirm Password"
                                                        type="password"
                                                        fullWidth
                                                        className={classes.textField}
                                                        value={this.state.cp_confirmPassword}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                        margin="normal"
                                                        required={true}
                                                    />
                                                </GridItem>
                                            </GridContainer>


                                        </CardBody>
                                        <CardFooter>

                                            <Button color="warning" onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} disabled={loading}>
                                                {loading && <CircularProgress style={{ color: 'white', height: '20px', width: '20px', marginRight: '10px' }} />}
                                                Change Password
                      </Button>
                                        </CardFooter>
                                    </GridItem>
                                </GridContainer>
                            </form>
                        </Card>

                    </GridItem>


                </GridContainer>


                <Snackbar
                    open={this.state.open}//{!!this.props.authError}//
                    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
                    message={message}
                    variant="error"
                    onClose={() => this.setState({ open: false, message: '' })}
                    action={
                        <IconButton
                            key="close"
                            aria-label="Close"
                            color="inherit"
                            className={classes.close}
                            onClick={() => 
                               // clearAuthError
                                this.setState({ open: false, message: '' })
                            
                            }
                        >
                            <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
                        </IconButton>
                    }
                    autoHideDuration={3000}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapstateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth,
        authError: state.authroot.autherr
    }
}
const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch, getState) => {
    return {
        changePassword: (currentPassword, newPassword, passwordUpdated) => { dispatch(changePassword(currentPassword, newPassword, passwordUpdated)) },
    }
}
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    connect(mapstateToProps, mapDispatchtoProps)
)(ChangePassword);
```

Comment: where do u call function `openScnackbar`? I not see any

Comment: Where are you calling ‘openSnackbar’?

Comment: Could you please add the code snippet where you are calling snackbar?

Comment: What is `<TextField>`? Where are you calling `openSnackbar`? On "success or error" of what?

Comment: on Authentication error I'm calling that function. and Even on submit i'm updating the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `handleSubmit` function don't pass `this.passwordUpdated`

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let curpass = this.state.cp_currentPassword
    let newpass = this.state.cp_newPassword
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.props.changePassword(curpass, newpass, this.passwordUpdated) //Remove this.passwordUpdated from here
}
```

Instead of `ComponentDidUpdate` method you should use `ComponentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', nextProps);
 if (this.props.authError !== nextProps.authError) {
  // here you can make your textbox empty
  this.setState({
      cp_currentPassword: '',
      cp_newPassword: '',
      cp_confirmPassword: ''
  });
 }
}
```

**Note:** In new version of react you must use static [getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`.